# Why would the derivate of u - 2 = x be du = xdx?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I am going through an integration requiring a u-substitution on a practice midterm, and the professor posted a solution which used:

u = x - 2

u - 2 = x

du = xdx

I am confused how du could be anything other than dx? From what I understand, the derivative of u - 2 and the derivative of u are identical. The way he did this was key to how he solved the problem. Here's the solution:
[image: Solution]

Comment: What I see here is that $du$ = $dx$.

Comment: The typesetting you have shown here is unfortunate.

Comment: Looks like a typo in the first sentence. The rest looks fine and unaffected by the typo though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$u=x+2 \implies \frac d{dx} (u)=\frac d{dx}(x+2) \implies \frac{du}{dx}=1\implies du=dx$$

What was written above in your book's solution ($du=x\,dx$) may be a typo.

Comment: Aye, it is indeed a typo.

Comment: I can't say that it was a typo, because he did this in front of all of us in review tonight. I couldn't grasp it though.

Comment: It is definitely a typo. Note that $du=x dx$ isn't actually being used in the lines below: the first $x$ is replaced with $u-2$, the $x+2$ is replaced with $u$, and the $dx$ is replaced with $du$. There is nowhere for a stray $x$ to be lurking.

Comment: When your professor did this in front of all of you, did anyone ask him?  Someone should have!  We all make slips from time to time.

Comment: You guys are right. I guess I was severely confused because no one else asked, and I thought he was unveiling a whole new method of integration to us. I heard a lot of "ooohhh"'s as if there were a grand realization to be had.